# Change image width/height with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

New to Javascript here,
I've been trying to change the size of an image (width/height) in an HTML page whenever a mouseover occurs, however it doesn't seem to work if the styles are set in the CSS page, which is a huge problem for me since I need to use the position property to set the image location.

Here's the code.

HTML:

```
<a  href="#"  onMouseOver="big()" onMouseOut="small()">
<img src="img1.png" name="image1" id="mw">
</a>
```

CSS:

```
#mw
{
    position:absolute;
    left:15%;
    top:35%;
    width:146px;
    height:97px;
}
```

jS:

```
function big()
{
    document.getElementsByName("image1").style.width=183;
    document.getElementsByName("image1").style.height=121;
}
function small()
{
    document.getElementsByName("image1").style.width=146;
    document.getElementsByName("image1").style.height=97;
}
```

Comment: You can do it with CSS only btw.

Comment: Fix your problem. http://jsbin.com/qicugikeza/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple javascript version, style not required

```js
var element = document.getElementsByName("image1")[0];
element.setAttribute('width', 146);
element.setAttribute('height', 97);

function big() {
  element.setAttribute('width', 183);
  element.setAttribute('height', 121);
}

function small() {
  element.setAttribute('width', 146);
  element.setAttribute('height', 97);
}
```

```html
<a href="#"  onMouseOver="big()" onMouseOut="small()">
  <img src="http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png" name="image1" id="mw">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by CSS only. There is a [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)-pseudo class which gets activated once you hover a specific element. For your request, there is no need to use JavaScript.

```
#mw:hover {
    width: 183px;
    height: 121px;
}
```

What the above CSS snippet does is: "*change width and height to respectively 183px and 121px if you hover an element with id mw*".

Here below is an example of it. click on "Run code snippet" and try to hover the rubic image.

```css
#mw {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  top: 35%;
  width: 146px;
  height: 97px;
}

#mw:hover {
  width: 183px;
  height: 121px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png" name="image1" id="mw">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
a:hover {transform:scale(1.5,1.5);}  <here you can set the x and y scaling
```

with JS you can:

```
document.getElement etc.addEventListener("your event", function(event){
event.target.style.transform = "scale(1.5,1.5)";
});
```